# AI Algorithm - connecting given pairs of vertices of a Matrix shaped graph without conflicts

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I am looking for AI algorithms to connect halls in a simple circuit, which I assumed that could be represented as a tow dimensional matrix which itself lead to a graph problem.
I cant find such algorithms, so I can add an heuristic to.
I am pretty sure that this is a famous AI problem but cant figure out its name,
Hopefully any body can tell me where to find such algorithms and assure me about that assumption of mine about the circuit and its representation as graph is true.
Thanks.

Comment: I've read somewhere that genetics algorithms are used in this kind of problems. They can help you finding the maximum of the euristic, as well as other algorithms like the hill climbing. I'm not an expert in this field even though I love it, hope my comment can point you in the right direction :)

Comment: I don't think that genetics algorithms are in this exact field .
I mean this problem is in my opinion like Eight-Queens and other similar Backtracking-based problems, but thanks any way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "connect halls", but if you are trying to lay out a circuit, maybe searching for "topological planar routing algorithm "  will help you in your search.

Also, the following article might give you ideas:
http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_(electronic_design_automation)

Comment: I am assigned of a research about the algorithms of connecting number of given holes in a simple electronic circuit with links, under specific conditions such as the links don't cross with each other nor with other holes.
there is a two dimensional matrix that represent the holes, therefore the 'routes' between those holes=the links positions. 
The algorithm's input is pairs of the holes wanted to be connected, the output is the links' positioning under the mentioned conditions.
I want to choose between those common algorithms a suitable one to add my heuristic and do the research.
thank you.

Comment: @aous-deeb [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/) is a good place to look for academic papers.   The following to papers might interest you [Advances in PCB Routing])https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/ipsjtsldm/5/0/5_0_14/_article)  and  [Routing for analog chip design at NXP semiconductors](www.cs.uu.nl/research/techreps/repo/CS-2011/2011-011.pdf)  The topics of the papers and the references cited in them ought to be of help in your search.